# Adding a created list item to another class

Tags: c#, list

I have an item, 'Part' that has been created

```
public void AddPart(int partNumber, string partName, string partDescription, decimal cost, decimal price, short Quantity)
{         
   m_supplierParts.Add(new Part(partNumber, partName, partDescription, cost, price, Quantity));           
}
```

then adding the part to the job

```
public void AddExistingPart(Part part)
{
    m_partUsed.Add(part);
}
```

What I then want to do is select that part and add it to another list, 'Job'.

The idea is, to add an existing part to a job.

I have selected the part

```
public List<Part> SelectPart(String PartRef)
 {
        List<Part> PartSet = new List<Part>();

        foreach (Part p in m_supplierParts)
        {
            if (p.PartNumber.ToString().Equals(PartRef, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                PartSet.Add(p);
        }
        return PartSet;
    }
```

But what I then want to do is add that found part to the list:

```
string selectedPart = cboJobParts.Text;
List<Part> foundPart = s.SelectPart(selectedPart);

j.AddExistingPart(foundPart); //Adding the found part
```

'j' being the reference to a job.

The error I'm having is that it's saying 'foundPart' cannot be converted.

Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'Auspex.Job.AddExistingPart(Auspex.Part)' has some invalid arguments

Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'Auspex.Part'

I'm not understanding why the found part cannot be passed through as a list item?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can't see where you are calling `AddExistingPart`

Comment: Have made the edit, had changed the name of the method but hadn't changed it on the add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `j.AddPart` function accepts a single `Part` object as parameter.
Your `SelectPart` function returns a `List<Part>` datatype.

When you want to add all the parts returned by `SelectPart` you have to iterate:

```
foreach(Part part in s.SelectPart(selectedPart)) {
    j.AddPart(part);
}
```

Or when your intention is that `SelectPart` just returns a single `Part` object, you have to change `SelectPart` to return a single `Part` object:

```
public Part SelectPart(String PartRef)
{
    return m_supplierParts.Single(p => p.PartNumber.ToString().Equals(
                                   PartRef, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
}
```

Comment: You could overload, `AddPart(List<part>)` then it accepts your list and would have to iterate like Jan said.

Comment: I don't want to scare you, but I could kiss you right now. That's what I was after, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a list of part wheras your add function expects only one part.